# Adding adjusted p-values to ggplot box plots

Tags: p-value, ggpubr

I know that this question has been asked before and I have looked at the solutions but they don't work for my situation. I have a small dataset (BCAAparams) that comprises the Km and Vmax values of an enzyme in the presence of different concentrations of an inhibitor (variables are Km, Vmax and Conc (of inhibitor)), n=6 of each.

```
Km  Vmax    Conc
0.32761 0.66823 0
0.31735 0.61598 0
0.462   0.722   0
0.31537 0.75304 0
0.28596 0.69695 0
0.25033 0.6482  0
0.24417 0.56245 2
0.25671 0.55012 2
0.24481 0.5027  2
0.2128  0.627   2
0.25104 0.64405 2
0.27557 0.65705 2
0.15244 0.46027 10
0.15438 0.41831 10
0.1457  0.37902 10
0.15884 0.52568 10
0.16006 0.5068  10
0.14318 0.47678 10
0.0879  0.34372 20
0.09132 0.32773 20
0.07899 0.28851 20
0.09257 0.38427 20
0.09333 0.37988 20
0.09315 0.36979 20
```

I am looking to analyse the effect of the inhibitor on each of the enzymes parameters, e.g.,

```
ggplot(BCAAparams, aes(group=Conc, x=Conc, y=Km)) +
geom_boxplot(notch=FALSE) + labs(x="BCAA conc (mM)", y="Km (mM)")
```

[image]

I'm using ggpubr and I can successfully compare the means of the different groups (concentrations of the inhibitor)

```
compare_means(Km ~ Conc, data = BCAAparams, method = "t.test") 

# A tibble: 6 x 8
.y.   group1 group2            p       p.adj p.format p.signif method
<chr> <chr>  <chr>         <dbl>       <dbl> <chr>    <chr>    <chr> 
1 Km    0      2      0.0432       0.043       0.04317  *        T-test
2 Km    0      10     0.00190      0.0038      0.00190  **       T-test
3 Km    0      20     0.000461     0.0014      0.00046  ***      T-test
4 Km    2      10     0.0000342    0.000140    3.4e-05  ****     T-test
5 Km    2      20     0.00000276   0.000014    2.8e-06  ****     T-test
6 Km    10     20     0.0000000135 0.000000081 1.3e-08  ****     T-test
```

The problem is that I can't find a way of adding the stat_compare_means command that would put the brackets and associated adjusted p-values onto my box-plot, e.g.,;

```
my_comparisons <- list(c("0", "2"), c("0", "10"), c("0", "20"), 
c("2","10"), c("2", "20"), c("10", "20"))

ggplot(BCAAparams, aes(group=Conc, x=Conc, y=Km)) +
geom_boxplot(notch=FALSE) + stat_compare_means(aes(label = "p.adj"), 
comparisons = my_comparisons, method = "t.test") + labs(x="BCAA conc 
(mM)", y="Km(mM)")
```

I get the error, "Discrete value supplied to continuous scale". I've tried moving the stat_compare_means command to other "locations" in the code and I've also tried what I've seen in other posts answering similar issues, setting up the box-plot as an object and then adding the stat_compare_means to it but nothing along those lines works. Does any one have any ideas what I'm doing wrong?